# Google map not centered on marker on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map toggle that when you open it isn't centered on the map marker. I've searched everything, and tried bunch but cannot solve this issue. The HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div class="hidden_map_wrapper" data-map_height="450px">
    <div class="hidden_map_heading">
        <h3>Locate us on map</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="google_map_1" data-map_type="ROADMAP" data-auto_center_zoom="0" data-lat="40.7782201" data-lng="-73.9733317" data-zoom="13" data-scrollwheel="0" data-maptypecontrol="1" data-pancontrol="1" data-zoomcontrol="1" data-scalecontrol="1" class="google_map" style="height: 450px; width: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);">
        //bunch of map HTML data here
    </div>
    <div class="google_map_marker" data-title="Our Company" data-icon="map_marker.png" data-lat="40.7782201" data-lng="-73.9733317">
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside `.google_map` there is a map that is generated by api already. Now on click I have:

```
$(".hidden_map_heading").click(function () {
    var $current_map = $(this).next(".google_map");
    var map_object = document.getElementById($current_map.attr('id'));

    $current_map.slideToggle({
        duration : 400,
        progress : function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map_object, 'resize');

        }
    });
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + $current_map.parent().data('map_height') }, 400);
});
```

This works, only I don't have my marker centered. I tried with the entire re initializing of the map, but that totally didn't work. I tried adding

```
var centerofmap = map_object.getCenter(); 
google.maps.event.trigger(map_object, 'resize'); 
map_object.setCenter(centerofmap);
```

In my `progress`, but that didn't work (got errors about non existing functions).

I'm a bit confused. Everywhere I look the `map_object` is something like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById($current_map.attr('id')),
                                            myOptions);
```

But this would mean that I am initializing the map, and the map is already there, initialized and ready. If I don't hide it, it works perfectly. The code for initializing the map looks like this:

```
function initialize_gmap($element) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($element.data('lat'),$element.data('lng'));
    var auto_center_zoom = ($element.data('auto_center_zoom') == 1 ? true : false);
    var scrollwheel = ($element.data('scrollwheel') == 1 ? true : false);
    var mapTypeControl = ($element.data('maptypecontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var panControl = ($element.data('pancontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var zoomControl = ($element.data('zoomcontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var scaleControl = ($element.data('scalecontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var styles = (typeof options !== 'undefined') ? options.custom_map_style : '';
    var map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;

    if ($element.data('map_type') == 'SATELLITE') map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
    if ($element.data('map_type') == 'HYBRID') map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
    if ($element.data('map_type') == 'TERRAIN') map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: parseInt($element.data('zoom'),10),
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: map_type,
        styles: jQuery.parseJSON(styles),
        scrollwheel: scrollwheel,
        mapTypeControl: mapTypeControl,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        },
        panControl: panControl,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        zoomControl: zoomControl,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: scaleControl,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        }
    };

    var elemnt_id = $element.attr('id');
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(elemnt_id), mapOptions);

    var c = 0;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindowContent = [];
    var marker_icons = [];
    $element.siblings('.google_map_marker').each(function(){
        var $marker = $(this);
        markers[c] = [$marker.data('title'), $marker.data('lat'),$marker.data('lng'),$marker.data('icon')];
        infoWindowContent[c] = ['<div class="info_content">' + '<h3>' + $marker.data('title') + '</h3>' + '<p>' + $marker.html() + '</p>' + '</div>'];
        c++;
    });

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: markers[i][3]
        });
        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    if(auto_center_zoom){
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

$('.google_map').each(function(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_gmap($(this)));
});
```

So, what am I missing here? How to make map centered on marker on resize?

### Solution

The trick is to put the map as a global object, as sabotero mentioned. This way I can use

```
$(".hidden_map_heading").click(function () {
    var $current_map = $(this).next(".google_map");

    $current_map.slideToggle({
        duration : 400,
        progress : function () {
            var centerofmap = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            map.setCenter(centerofmap);
        }
    });
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + $current_map.parent().data('map_height') }, 400);
});
```

And it will work on resize.

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(map_object, 'resize', function(){ // recenter here the map on the marker });

Comment: also `var map` has to be global

Comment: And how to recenter the marker? Manually? I've tried by adding `var centerofmap = map_object.getCenter();` and then inside your suggestion `map_object.setCenter(centerofmap);`, but I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: map_object.getView is not a function`

Comment: No, yo have to center the map in the marker not the marker in the map. So: var center = new google.maps.latLng(marker.lat(),marker.lng()), there is your center

Comment: And don't use  `map_object`, use `map` and made it global

Comment: Thing is my map is already initialized. I'm not re initializing it again. Just reading of the map id.

Comment: Plus I can have to be able to have multiple maps on a page, and multiple markers (as you can see from my code that initializes the maps).

Comment: ok, you don't have to initialize the map again, but you have to pass the google.maps.map object and not the id, it can't be either the `div` or container of the map, it has to be the actual object. Pass then `$current_map` if your are sure it is a google.maps.map object. It is because of that that you are getting errors on no existing functions

Comment: I think your `$current_map`variable is a `jQuery` object containing the div, and it is not suitable to pass in `addListener` or `trigger` and neither to do `$current_map.setCenter(center);`

Comment: You have to have a method to stock globaly the map objects of all your maps and a method for be able to retreive the one you want whenever and wherever you want it

Comment: Ok, why the -1? This was a valid question with all the code provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all made `var map` global

```
var map;    
function initialize_gmap($element) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($element.data('lat'),$element.data('lng'));
    var auto_center_zoom = ($element.data('auto_center_zoom') == 1 ? true : false);
    var scrollwheel = ($element.data('scrollwheel') == 1 ? true : false);
    var mapTypeControl = ($element.data('maptypecontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var panControl = ($element.data('pancontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var zoomControl = ($element.data('zoomcontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var scaleControl = ($element.data('scalecontrol') == 1 ? true : false);
    var styles = (typeof options !== 'undefined') ? options.custom_map_style : '';
    var map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;

    if ($element.data('map_type') == 'SATELLITE') map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
    if ($element.data('map_type') == 'HYBRID') map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
    if ($element.data('map_type') == 'TERRAIN') map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: parseInt($element.data('zoom'),10),
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: map_type,
        styles: jQuery.parseJSON(styles),
        scrollwheel: scrollwheel,
        mapTypeControl: mapTypeControl,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        },
        panControl: panControl,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        zoomControl: zoomControl,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: scaleControl,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        }
    };

    var elemnt_id = $element.attr('id');
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
////////////////////////
////// map is global ///
////////////////////////
/////////////////////////
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(elemnt_id), mapOptions);

    var c = 0;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindowContent = [];
    var marker_icons = [];
    $element.siblings('.google_map_marker').each(function(){
        var $marker = $(this);
        markers[c] = [$marker.data('title'), $marker.data('lat'),$marker.data('lng'),$marker.data('icon')];
        infoWindowContent[c] = ['<div class="info_content">' + '<h3>' + $marker.data('title') + '</h3>' + '<p>' + $marker.html() + '</p>' + '</div>'];
        c++;
    });

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: markers[i][3]
        });
        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    if(auto_center_zoom){
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

$('.google_map').each(function(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_gmap($(this)));
});
```

then in your progress function :

```
$(".hidden_map_heading").click(function () {
    var $current_map = $(this).next(".google_map");
    var map_object = document.getElementById($current_map.attr('id'));

    $current_map.slideToggle({
        duration : 400,
        progress : function () {
             google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function(){ 
            var center = new google.maps.latLng(marker.lat(),marker.lng());
                   map.setCenter(center);
});
            google.maps.event.trigger(map_object, 'resize');

        }
    });
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + $current_map.parent().data('map_height') }, 400);
});
```

Comment: what did you get? I assume you change `marker` for an actual valid object for it to work ?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, but I just used the `var centerofmap = map.getCenter(); google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); map.setCenter(centerofmap);` code, and I guess because the map is global it works now. Thanks for the tip!